# Catch all exceptions and then close Com port

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

I'm modifying a non-trivial program (with 2 threads) that sends and receives data down a serial connection.  Quite often, because of an unexpected error (or bad coding on my part :) ) the program terminates and the COM port is left open.  On next subsequent run, I then get an error  when attempting to open the COM port.  I would like to try and full mitigate against this happening and make sure that no matter where an error occurs -  a piece of failsafe code is run and attempts to close the COM port.

Can I get away with wrapping the whole program in one try/except/finally block or will I have to micro-manage each thread/class?
regards
Simon

Edited code if that helps

```
#usual python imports etc
...
board = pyfirmata.Arduino("COM26", baudrate=57600) # Replace COM26 with your Arduino port
...
#vairable initilistation


class MyError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self.value)

class ScratchSender(threading.Thread):
    #one of the threads


class ScratchListener(threading.Thread):
    #the other thread

#bit of code

def cleanup_threads(threads):
    for thread in threads:
        thread.stop()

    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        host = sys.argv[1]
    else:
        host = DEFAULT_HOST

cycle_trace = 'start'
while True:

    if (cycle_trace == 'disconnected'):
        cleanup_threads((listener, sender))
        time.sleep(1)
        cycle_trace = 'start'

    if (cycle_trace == 'start'):
        listener = ScratchListener(the_socket)
        sender = ScratchSender(the_socket)
        cycle_trace = 'running'
        listener.start()
        sender.start()

    # wait for ctrl+c
    try:
        #bit of code
        #print "motorA val:" , motorA

        if ((motorA > 0) or (motorB > 0)):
            #do something
        else:
            #just let the threads do their stuff in the background
            time.sleep(0.1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        cleanup_threads((listener,sender))
        board.exit()
        sys.exit()
```

Comment: It'd help if you showed relevant parts of your code - otherwise, it's a bit of guess work

Comment: Seems like you could answer the `try/except/finally` question yourself -- by trying it.

Comment: Yes - I could "try" but I'm working hard on the progran inards :) and I'm no expert in nested exception handling so looking for some guidance to save time :)  The current code(which I didn't write) seems to deal with Ctrl-C quite well but not other exceptions (or as I call them - errors in my coding :) )